# How can I center this page?

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm creating a portfolio and want to know how I can make it center itself on the browser page.  The link to it is
http://optiq-portfolio.zxq.net/portfolio.html

I tried adding

```
margin-left:0 auto;
margin-right:0 auto;
```

to the body in css, but that's not working.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There's more to it than just that. You need to define a wrapper div, set the width on that, and then use `margin: 0 auto`

For instance, if you had your `body` defined with `width:1000px;` it'll already be centered. Of course, this messes up the rest of your stuff.

`margin-left: 0 auto` isn't valid also.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to add margins to your body, the proper way to handle this is to have a container element with `margin: 0px auto; text-align:left;`. On your body element you will want `text-align:center;`.

The rest of your code should be contained within the container element.

This will center your page in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you need to create a wrapper container so that it encloses your main content. Then specify a fixed width and automatic horizontal margins with CSS. David Walsh has a nice explanation of this in his blog post [Horizontally Center Your Website Structure Using CSS](http://davidwalsh.name/center-website).

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">

        <!-- WEBSITE GOES HERE -->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#wrap { 
    width: 900px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`margin-left: 0 auto;` and `margin-right: 0 auto;` are not valid CSS properties.

You can do something like `margin:0 auto;` which will set top and bottom to 0 and left and right to auto.